# Electron - How to get process argv from all electron pids

Tags: node.js, electron, ipc

I have an electron app with multiple browserWindows.
For my own help, I spawn them with additional arguments (for example: '--renderer-mode="second-window"').

Now I want to collect Metric Data of my current electron processes.
I already have a IPC interface in my main process I call from one of my renderer.

```
ipcMain.handle('app-metrics', (event, message) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const appMetrics = app.getAppMetrics()
        resolve(appMetrics)
    })
})
```

Here I want to add all the argv from my apps processes.
I don't know how I could get the info in this function. I only know the way with `process.argv`, but how could I collect these info from all the sub processes and bundle it with my `appMetrics` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question in another way. My goal was to display the "process" type (not the chromium types that already exists in the metric data).

I'm collecting the PIDs I already know and hardcode them a specific type. The next thing was to add this info into the metric object. Here is my result:

```
ipcMain.handle('app-metrics', (event, message) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const pids = [
            {
                name: 'main-process',
                pid: process.pid
            },
            {
                name: 'app-gui',
                pid: this.win.webContents.getOSProcessId()
            },
            {
                name: 'popup-gui',
                pid: this.winPopup.webContents.getOSProcessId()
            }
        ]

        const appMetrics = app.getAppMetrics().map((metric) => {
            const pidType = pids.filter((e) => e.pid === metric.pid)
            if (pidType.length > 0) {
                return {
                    ...metric,
                    appType: pidType[0].name
                }
            }
            return {
                ...metric,
                appType: ''
            }
        })
        resolve(appMetrics)
    })
})
```

If there is a simpler and smarter way, I'm happy to hear it. :)